# React-Native buttons are not formatting correctly on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm using [react-native-circular-action-menu](https://github.com/geremih/react-native-circular-action-menu) for popout navigation buttons. On iPhone it looks as expected (note the circle buttons):

[image: iPhone]

But on Android it's being constrained into a box:

[image]

Here is the relevant code for this component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';
import colors from '../../../styles/colors';
import formStyles from '../../../styles/formStyles';

import ActionButton from 'react-native-circular-action-menu';
import Icon from '../../../assets/components/svgIcons.js';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../../actions';
import apiHelper from "../../../utils/api";
import { NavigationActions, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


class ProfileCircleNav extends Component {

    renderImage() {
      return(
        <Image
          source={require("../../../assets/images/LexodyL.png")}
          style={{height: 70, width: 70}}
        />
      )
    }

    renderButton() {
      if(!this.state.blocked) {
        return(
          <View style={{minHeight: 200, width: 350}}>
          <ActionButton
            buttonColor={colors.rgbaGreen}
            outRangeScale={.5}
            btnOutRange={colors.halfGreen}
            bgColor={'transparent'}
            position={"right"}
            radiua={200}
            icon={this.renderImage()}
            onPress={this.props.onPress}
            style={{zIndex: 12}}
          >
            <ActionButton.Item buttonColor={'transparent'}  title="Request Lex" onPress={() => {this.createMeeting()}}>
              <View style={styles.actionButton}>
                <Icon
                    name='Calendar'
                    strokeWidth="3"
                    stroke={'#fff'}
                    fill={'#fff'}
                  />
                <Text style={formStyles.textStandard}>Schedule</Text>
                <Text style={formStyles.textStandard}>Lex</Text>
              </View>
            </ActionButton.Item>
            <ActionButton.Item buttonColor={'transparent'} style={styles.actionButtonIcon} title="Chat" onPress={() => this.startConvo()}>
              <View style={styles.actionButton}>
                <Icon
                    name='Chat'
                    strokeWidth="3"
                    stroke={'#fff'}
                    fill={'#fff'}
                  />
                  <Text style={formStyles.textStandard}>Chat</Text>
              </View>
            </ActionButton.Item>
          </ActionButton>
          </View>
        )
      }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{
              bottom: Dimensions.get('window').height*.50,
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            }}>
              {this.renderButton()}

            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  actionButtonIcon: {
      height: 500,
      fontSize: 50,
    },
    actionButton: {
      backgroundColor: colors.green,
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      borderRadius: 50,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    currentUser: state.currentUser
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ProfileCircleNav);
```

I've been trying to figure this out for hours - what am I missing here? Why is it a square on Android?

Comment: `radiua={200}` you have some misspelling here.

Comment: @KevinAmiranoff thanks for the help, but that is not a misspelling - I linked the docs in the first line.

Comment: hum, are you sure : https://github.com/geremih/react-native-circular-action-menu/blob/5034d14c31875df623b6490034105f6426c15ecf/ActionButton.js#L195

Comment: the misspelling is also in there readme. But it does not explain why it works on ios. Anyway that is my only shot.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Check the official docs: https://github.com/geremih/react-native-circular-action-menu You're referencing ActionButtonItem, whereas ActionButton takes `radiua` according to the official docs. Plus, I tried changing it to `radius` to entertain the idea, and it makes no difference - the buttons on Android are still squares. Also - I'm not sure that would explain why it works fine on iPhone and not Android?

Comment: Ok that might not solve the issue, but there is no `radiua` in the whole source code. That is the propType declaration: https://github.com/geremih/react-native-circular-action-menu/blob/5034d14c31875df623b6490034105f6426c15ecf/ActionButton.js#L274

Comment: Okay - good to know. thanks! Any thoughts for the square buttons?

Comment: the issue comes from `height: 100,width: 100,`. it does apply a borderRadius is you try with `20` instead of `100`. I believe. Not sure why though.

Comment: I'm confused - are you saying to make the borderRadius 20, or the height? A height and width of 20 will not be big enough to contain the icon and words in the button.

Comment: Sorry, give me a minute, I am writing an answer (to your question).

Comment: you have to use `size` prop to `ActionButton.Item`, not `height: 500,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the issue you have is that height here has no effect.

```
  actionButtonIcon: {
      height: 500,
      fontSize: 50,
    },
```

what you have to do is use the prop `size` to `ActionButton.Item`. I think a size bigger or equal than the borderRadius of `100` you are trying to apply.

```
        <ActionButton.Item buttonColor={'transparent'} size={100}  title="Request Lex" onPress={() => {this.createMeeting()}}>
```

Here is a working example: https://snack.expo.io/ByG7nsVwQ

You can see the prop used in the code [right here](https://github.com/geremih/react-native-circular-action-menu/blob/5034d14c31875df623b6490034105f6426c15ecf/ActionButtonItem.js#L50)

Comment: You're a saint. Thank you!! That's exactly what the issue was! Weird that only Android was effected by that.

Comment: Thanks! That is weird indeed!